# Trying to access array object in JS gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this JS output

[image]

I'm trying to access the first member of the ModelState array using this approach:

```
console.log(data.ModelState[0]);
```

But I'm getting undefined error.

Also when trying to do alert(data.ModelState) I'm getting Object object.

How can I access the first value in the ModelState array?

Comment: I believe that is an object that has a blank key (or maybe whitespace?) which has an array as a value. So you need something like `data.ModelState[""][0]`

Comment: In which browser you are testing this? @Laziale

Comment: @RanojitBanerjee that's Firefox. More specifically, the Firebug extension.

Comment: @vlaz pls provide your comment as answer so I can select that as correct answer. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appears that your data contains an array which has a blank or whitespace key. So it most likely looks like this

```
{
    ModelState: {
        "": [ "string1", "string2" ]
    }
}
```

You would need to access it via the key there, as long as you know what it is, for example `data.ModelState[""][1] //"string1"`

There are also alternatives if you are not sure what they key would be or want a less brittle code:

```js
 var data = {
   ModelState: {
     "": [ "string1", "string2" ]
   }
 };

console.log("--Using Object.keys--")
Object.keys(data.ModelState).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(data.ModelState[key]);
})

console.log("--Using for...in loop--")
for (var key in data.ModelState) {
  console.log(data.ModelState[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to access it using `data.ModelState[''][0]`.  It seems you have a nested array, with the element of the array containing the two strings has an empty or whitespace-only string for an index.

Answer (score 0):

`[object Object]` is your first clue there—although I can’t reproduce your exact problem, it looks like the object you think is an array is actually a [JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), which is a different data structure. JS Objects are fairly similar to objects from other object oriented languages. Their string representation is, as you’ve noticed, `[object Object]]`, regardless of their contents.

```
> String({})
< "[object Object]"
> String({abc: "foo", def: "bar"})
< "[object Object]"
```

If you update your question with steps on how to reproduce it, I can help more, but I hope that’s enough to get you on the right track!